# ¿Como omitir una función después de realizar click para cargar la pagina con datos de la base de datos?

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy haciendo una pagina que muestra a todo el personal de una escuela, para poder mostrar los datos de un profesor basta con hacer click en la imagen correspondiente. Para ello realice un div que contiene los datos del maestro, este div se oculta cuando se carga la pagina gracias a un script, el div aparece después de hacer click en la imagen con otro script.

A continuación muestro el script que lo esconde

`var box = $('#Prof');
$('.img') .on ('load', function() {
            box.addClass('visuallyhidden');
            box.addClass('hidden');
        });`

Script que muestra el div después de hacer click en la imagen

```
 var box = $('#Prof');

 $('.img').on('click', function () {
 if (box.hasClass('hidden')) {

    box.removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
      box.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }, 20);

  }
});
```

Este es el código html

```
<div id="Prof" class="Prof">
<div class="fotoprof">
        <img src="imagen/foto10.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col1">
    <h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">Nombre: <?php echo "$titulo"; ?></h2>
    <h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">Cargo:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <h2 style="padding-left: 50px;">Actividad:</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="cerrar" onclick="ocultar()">Cerrar</div>
</div>
```

Mi problema es cuando hago click en la imagen y envió una variable con el identificador del maestro a la url que me servirá para traer los datos por medio del método GET y para ello la pagina se debe cargar nuevamente debido al envió de la variable, una vez que se carga la pagina nuevamente **quiero que el script que esconde el Div no se ejecute para que muestre los datos que se cargaron.**

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas AJAX?

Comment: Pero como lo haría?

Comment: ¿De dónde se obtiene el id del maestro cuando se clickea la imagen?

Comment: Ese id esta predefinido, lo muestro a continuación.                                                     <img class="imagen/foto10.png" onclick="location.href = 'personal.php?id=1'">

Comment: Primero, aprende cómo usar AJAX y cómo comunicarse con PHP mediante AJAX y JSON, ya que hay que hacer lo siguiente: primero, debes cambiar `personal.php` para que reciba el id del profesor, realice una consulta y el resultset lo devuelva como JSON. Segundo, enviar el id del profesor desde el cliente mediante AJAX en cuanto se haga click en la imagen. El resto, es cuestión solamente de mostrar los datos en el HTML.

Comment: Hola, estoy aprendiendo lo que me sugeriste pero me encontré con un problema creo yo bastante fácil, pero que no se resolver y tampoco el motivo, pues cuando intento consultar un registro de la bd muestra solo algunos o ningún registro y desconozco el motivo, e intentado cambiar de tabla o de base de datos y pero no consigo solucionar el problema.